# Testing base-62 converter

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I have a converter module which encodes non-negative numerics to base 62 strings and vice versa.

I'm not very experienced with testing, and I got this so far:

**Encode**

- Test for negative numbers
- Test for non-numerics
- Test result for basic input

**Decode**

- Test for numerics
- Test result for basic input

**Codec - encode and decode**

- encoding randomly generated numbers and decoding them back to check the result

**What is the best approach for testing such a module?**

Comment: What language are you writing the module in? That is a factor in deciding which error and boundary conditions to test for.

Comment: Node.js and Jasmine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have most of what you should test. For most modules, you should focus your tests on

- *Behaviour for well-formed input*: Verify that the encoder can convert numbers to their correct base-62 representation and that the decoder can convert a valid base-62 representation to the corresponding number. Pick your numbers such that you can verify as many features of the base-62 representation as possible.
- *Behaviour for malformed input*: Verify that the encoder handles invalid input (negative numbers, wrong type, etc.) appropriately. The same for invalid input to the decoder (wrong type, a string that isn't a valid base-62 representation, etc.)
- *Boundary conditions*: Test for edge-cases in valid input (for example, 0 or the largest possible number), or numbers that might be troublesome for your algorithm (for example, should the result of `encode(10)` be `a` or `A`?)